# Skipping specific rows and columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, read.csv

I skipped second row of the data using this command:

```
Df=(read.csv(“IMDB_data.csv”, header=T, sep=",")[-2,])
```

What is the explanation behind this?
Can it be used for skipping more than 1 specific row?
Can it used for skipping columns?
Please help.

Comment: yes and yes. although you are not "skipping" but subsetting, see `help('[')`

Comment: @rawr Thanks a lot, bro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can "skip" as many rows using negative values, i.e.

```
Df=(read.csv(“IMDB_data.csv”, header=T, sep=",")[-c(2,3,5:9),])
```

Similar for columns:

```
Df=(read.csv(“IMDB_data.csv”, header=T, sep=",")[, -c(2,4)])
```

To skip rows and columns

```
Df=(read.csv(“IMDB_data.csv”, header=T, sep=",")[-c(2,3,5:9), -c(2,4)])
```